# When do I use HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning to code and I am in doubt about using HTML or JavaScript. For me, there are some things that JS does that is simpler with HTML.  For example:

- The action of submitting a form in html I can do with the  tag `"<input type= 'submit'>"` and add an action. What is the advantage of using `"example.addEventListener('submit', function(e)...)"` ?
- If I want to put a link on my website, I can do that with the tag `<a href="website url">link</a>`. Why would I use something like `window.open("website url")`?

I don't know if my question was clear, but basically I am trying to understand if there is a "best practice" or if JS enables me doing something that HTML doesn't in this cases.

When I am coding, it is better if I do things more simply, right?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Links are links.. buttons are buttons.. JavaScript "runs code, to do whatever logic". Don't need it, because it's already supported in 'just HTML'? Don't use it.

Comment: submit requires an action to function, usually this is done by JavaScript but sometimes can also be done using back end code; HTML isn't enough in any case.

Comment: This is opinion based.  I'd love to tell you that your site should always be able to run even if JavaScript is disabled, but there will be 5 other users that will tell you that that isn't realistic in 2020 and that there are projects where it just plain doesn't make sense.  If you are running a single page application and want to submit your form over AJAX without triggering a navigation, you use JS, otherwise you use `form#target` and let the browser do the work.  We can't narrow this down to an exact answer, it varies from project to project.

Comment: There's no `submit` tag in HTML ... If you're talking about `form` tag, and comparing the tag to a submit listener, those are two totally distinct features. A submit listener doesn't work without a form. In general, if you can do things you need with pure HTML, then that's the way to go, but if you ever need more control over something, or you need somenthing HTML can't provide, then you need JS. Ex. [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) can do a lot of customizing with the window to open and return data to the main page, which an anchor tag can't do.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the comment! I was thinking abouT the `input` tag with `type="submit"`.

Comment: You use HTML to express the semantics of the content of the website. And JavaScript to enhance the site with features that cannot be solved with HTML alone. But the priority is to have correct semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The action of submitting a form in html I can do with the tag "" and add an action. What is the advantage of using "example.addEventListener('submit', function(e)...)" ?

Sometimes, you need to do something programmatically with the form data.  For example, rather than submitting the form directly to a URL, JavaScript can handle the form data and load data from the server.

> If I want to put a link on my website, I can do that with the tag link. Why would I use something like window.open("website url")?

You usually wouldn't.  If you have a specific example, please share it, as there may be an edge case.